# Trying to resolve no such column: blog_comment.url

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Once a user had logged into my site he could write a post and update it.

Then I was making progress in adding functionality which allowed people to make comments. I was at the stage where I could add comments from the back end and they would be accurately displayed on the front end.

Now when I try and update posts I get an error message. Originally I thought the problem was because I had not included a slug field and made the appropriate migrations. I then deleted the specific section of the code which was highlighted in the error message but it just meant the next line of code got flagged up instead.

[image]
[image]

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.text import slugify
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse


# Create your models here.
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content =  models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    url= models.SlugField(max_length=500, unique=True, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.url= slugify(self.title)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title 

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('article_detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})


class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='comments')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    email = models.EmailField()
    body = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    url= models.SlugField(max_length=500, unique=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['created_on']

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Comment {} by {}'.format(self.body, self.name)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.url= slugify(self.post)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('article_detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
```

**views.py**

```
def post_detail(request, pk):
template_name = 'post_detail.html'

comments = Comment.objects.filter(post=pk ,active=True)
post = Post.objects.get(pk=pk)
new_comment = None
# Comment posted
if request.method == 'POST':
    comment_form = CommentForm(data=request.POST)
    if comment_form.is_valid():

        # Create Comment object but don't save to database yet
        new_comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
        # Assign the current post to the comment
        new_comment.post = post
        # Save the comment to the database
        new_comment.save()
else:
    comment_form = CommentForm()

return render(request, template_name, {'post': post,
                                       'comments': comments,
                                       'new_comment': new_comment,
                                       'comment_form': comment_form})
```

**Update - Migrations**

I have now made (or attempted to make) the necessary migrations.

```
WARNINGS:
?: (2_0.W001) Your URL pattern '^activate/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$' [name='activate'] has a route that contains '(?P<', begins with a '^', or ends with a '$'. This was likely an oversight when migrating to django.urls.path().
blog.Post.date_posted: (fields.W161) Fixed default value provided.
        HINT: It seems you set a fixed date / time / datetime value as default for this field. This may not be what you want. If you want to have the current date as default, use `django.utils.timezone.now`
Migrations for 'blog':
  blog\migrations\0014_auto_20200420_2034.py
    - Add field url to comment
    - Alter field date_posted on post
```

**Update - Modified created_on**

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='comments')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    email = models.EmailField()
    body = models.TextField()
    created_on= models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now())
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    url= models.SlugField(max_length=500, unique=True, blank=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the field to following :

```
created_on= models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now())
```

Please study the documentation:

1.https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/